# Load link to images, only when visible in lightbox

Tags: html, css, image, lightbox, lightbox2

I have a question about loading (hidden) images, only when they are visible in a lightbox sequence when loaded in HTML as a link.
This is my code:

```
<a href="../img/image_A_large" rel="lightbox[sequence_A]" data-title="© 2021">
   <img src="../img/image_A_small.jpg">
   <h2>Images</h2>
</a>
   <a href="../img/image_B.jpg" rel="lightbox[sequence_A]" data-title="© 2021"></a>
   <a href="../img/image_C.jpg" rel="lightbox[sequence_A]" data-title="© 2021"></a>
   <a href="../img/image_D.jpg" rel="lightbox[sequence_A]" data-title="© 2021"></a>
   <a href="../img/image_E.jpg" rel="lightbox[sequence_A]" data-title="© 2021"></a>
   <a href="../img/image_F.jpg" rel="lightbox[sequence_A]" data-title="© 2021"></a>
   <a href="../img/image_G.jpg" rel="lightbox[sequence_A]" data-title="© 2021"></a>
   <a href="../img/image_H.jpg" rel="lightbox[sequence_A]" data-title="© 2021"></a>
   <a href="../img/image_I.jpg" rel="lightbox[sequence_A]" data-title="© 2021"></a>
   <a href="../img/image_J.jpg" rel="lightbox[sequence_A]" data-title="© 2021"></a>
```

Basically, it loads an image (image_A_large) in a lightbox pop-up when the small one is clicked (image_A_small). Within this lightbox pop-up, one can navigate to other images which are loaded with a link, in order to add them to the current lightbox sequence (image_B, image_C, image_D, image_E, etc.).

However, all these images are loaded when accessing the site. But I want them only to load when they will be visible in the lightbox sequence (or when the lightbox sequence is opened in general, if the former is a bit too complicated). There are 12 of these similar sequences on 5 different pages, so it loads quite slow and also drains a lot of my available bandwidth.

Any ideas on how I can achieve this?

Cheers!

Comment: lazy loading is the key word you want to search for. https://web.dev/browser-level-image-lazy-loading/

Comment: Lazy loading seems only to be implementable when the images are loaded with the <img> tag, not with the <a> tag. I need this <a> tag to link the images to the lightbox sequence.

Comment: Usually lightbox scripts (like Fancybox) loads current and next/previous image, therefore I'm not sure if your concern is justified.